# ld: warning : Xcode 8.3.2 build upload secsses but not see the build in iTunes connect activity

Tags: objective-c, xcode, firebase

ld: warning : Xcode 8.3.2 build upload success, but not see the build in iTunes connect activity

This is my podfile :

```
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/AdMob'
  pod 'Firebase/Crash'
```

I try to update cocapods : `sudo gem install cocoapods`
and after this : `pod update`

And its still have this 3 warning

Apple Developer Forums :

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/75793

```
ld: warning: Linker asked to preserve internal global: '__block_literal_global'
ld: warning: Linker asked to preserve internal global: '__block_descriptor_tmp'
ld: warning: Linker asked to preserve internal global: 'sharedInstance.sharedInstance'
```

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem after I run this in terminal :

cd ~
mv .itmstransporter/ .old_itmstransporter/
"/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application Loader.app/Contents/itms/bin/iTMSTransporter"

Comment: May solve it on iTunesConnect but doesn't explain the link warnings (clearly related to admob or some other google library)