# Xcode Apple Mach-O Linker (id) Warning

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, warnings

I have this app, with 0 errors and warnings when I run it on my device. But when I try to archive it for iTunes Connect I get all these weird `Apple Mach-O Linker (id) Warnings`.

There are two types of these warnings:

1. `Linker asked to preserve internal global: '__block_descriptor_tmp'`
2. `Linker asked to preserve internal global: '__block_literal_global'`

And the craziest part is that I get 402 of these warnings!
[image]

I have a suspicion these errors may come from, or has something to do with the ***Derived Data folder*** of my application. I have tried deleting it, but the errors just comes back.

Do you think it will be safe to just ignore the warnings and upload it to the App Store?

Comment: It could be related to a third party library you might be using; maybe (`pod update`) if using CocoaPods....

Comment: Dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43968312/ld-warning-xcode-8-3-2-build-upload-secsses-but-not-see-the-build-in-itunes-c where the OP answered his own question but didn't accept it.  See if that works.

Comment: Could it be related to frameworks? I recently added Google Ads, Facebook Audience Network, Chartboost and Unity frameworks and adapters to get ads into my app.

Comment: I think it is. I'm using Firebase for Google Admob and I get as many warnings...

Answer (score 3):

In case someone runs into the same problem, I just wanted to write an udpate: I haven't found a way to get rid of the warnings, but the app update in question went through the review process and is live on the app store with no reported issues. This is a known issue that's from upstream Firebase.

Comment: Yeah I'm still having this issue too, but the app/Firebase backend work just fine.

Answer (score 3):

It has something to do with Firebase and bitcode. They go away if you set `Enable bitcode` to false.

[image: enable bitcode]

Comment: Is there any other way as bitcode is very essential functionality.

Comment: @AmitVerma I'm not sure, but looks like there's no warnings on the latest firebase pod version (without disabling bitcode) for me